# What makes the colours in UHD demo footage so vibrant?

Tags: color

Whatever display you watch 4k and 8k demo footage on (I'm watching it in 1080p), the colours are so much more vibrant and engaging than 4k footage shot on phones, filmed for and shown on broadcast TV, and often films too. (See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyKZoqe8NdY) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1La4QzGeaaQ))

Why is this and what would I need to capture similarly colourful content? I'm aware that you can fake it in post-processing, is that all that's been done here?

Comment: Welcome! It is a little unclear from how you worded your question, but are you asking why do colors look more vibrant on material shot for broadcast or cinema than they do when shot on a phone?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLiebman! I think those demo videos have colours that are a lot brighter and bolder than similar footage shot at the same resolution (4k), which can be shot on phones, and footage shot on APS-C sized sensors. My question really comes down to what tech enables you to capture colourful footage?

Comment: @SamW to put the thing in a simple way. Probably the footage was done in raw then edited and graded in a professional way. It isn't a footage just took out of a phone camera.

Comment: To expand on that, it isn't just one technology, it is several including the quality of the sensor, the lenses, and the on-board processing. But it is more than just the technology, it is also the skill and artistry of everyone who touches the footage from cinematographer to colorist to editor.